# Lua calling main function of C++ binary

Tags: c++, lua

I was talking to someone very familiar with Lua language today and she was something very nice to do is to call the main() function of a C++ application. This supposedly gives one binary and makes versioning very simple.

I realized later I didn't understand. Is this concept reasonably common? Does anyone see more clearly its advantages?

Comment: Calling `main` is not supported by the standard.  Perhaps ask for some clarification?  `main` is called from the startup code and may not be called again.

Comment: Calling main() is prohibited by the C++ standard.  So I'm not sure why she thought it was something very nice to do, unless she was being sarcastic by recommending doing something prohibited in the language.

Comment: Richard and Eljay are referring to what you cannot do within a C++ program. An encapsulating environment can of course invoke `main()` — how else would your program be started? We're venturing _outside_ of the standard's jurisdiction here.

Comment: Not sure if your question is about integrating C++ and Lua in general or only about calling "main" from Lua but if it's the former, I know that Flexera licensing software has a "tamper-resistance" package that gives the developer the ability to integrate Lua functions with existing C or C++ code code and have the Lua invoke that C code.   I've used it.